# Implicit wait is not working within the framework

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Please give me reasonable solution. I have applied ImplicitWait and its ignoring the wait time and failing the script. what should I do to get it work. The web site takes around 10-15 sec to load, I put wait time for 45 seconds. Its waiting around 3-4 sec and throwing an error.

Here is the BaseClass code of my framework:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.ABC.PageObjects.LoginPage;
import com.ABC.Utilities.ReadConfig;

public class BaseClass {

    ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();
    public String baseUrl = readconfig.getApplicationUrl();
    public String baseUrl1 = readconfig.getApplicationUrl1();
    public String username = readconfig.getUsername();
    public String password = readconfig.getPassword();  
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Logger log;

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    public void SetUp(String br) throws IOException {

        log = Logger.getLogger("ABC");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

        if(br.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",readconfig.getChropath());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();    
        }
        else if(br.equals("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",readconfig.getFirefoxpath());
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();   
        }
        else if(br.equals("ie")) {
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",readconfig.getFirefoxpath());
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();  
        }

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// its waiting only 3-4 sec  
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(baseUrl);

    }



    @AfterClass(enabled = true)
    public void TearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    public void captureScreen(WebDriver driver, String tname) throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File target = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + tname + ".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, target);
        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
    }
```

---

This is the test case where Implicit wait its not working

```
public class TC_001_LoginTest extends BaseClass {

    @Test
        public void Login() throws IOException {
            log.info("url is opened");
            LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
                lp.setUserName(username);
                log.info("Username entered");
                    lp.setPassword(password);
                    log.info("Password entered");
                        lp.clickSubmit();
                        log.info("clicked");`
```

Anyone knows whats going on?

This is my page objects class

```
public class LoginPage {

        WebDriver ldriver;

        public LoginPage(WebDriver rdriver)
        {
            ldriver=rdriver;
            PageFactory.initElements(rdriver, this);
        }

        @FindBy(name="username")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement txtUserName;

        @FindBy(id="password")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement txtPassword;

        @FindBy(id="btnLogin")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement btnLogin;

        public void setUserName(String uname)
        {
            txtUserName.sendKeys(uname);
        }

        public void setPassword(String pwd)
        {
            txtPassword.sendKeys(pwd);
        }


        public void clickSubmit()
        {
            btnLogin.click();
        }
```

Comment: Your code implies that you're using page objects and probably page factory.  Please share that appropriate code with your original post as well.  When you initialize a page object with page factory, it has its own implicit wait parameter.

Comment: Thanks for response Bill. Yes I am using Page Objects. I updated my original post and added page objects class. I appreciate your help

Comment: Can you be more specific than "throws an error?"  Post your stacktrace.  Also, it might possibly be that you're passing the driver parameter to the initElements instead of the local copy.  Subsequent calls to the page object would likely fail.

Comment: here what it says:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <mat-icon _ngcontent-c5="" class="dropdown-expand-btn mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">...</mat-icon> is not clickable          -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------So its enters username and password then clicks submit. And I want to perform couple actons after logging in. So logging in takes around 10 sec but it throws that error message after 2-3 sec. Implicit wait not working at all

Comment: I used same exact framework for different project and implicit wait was working properly. but in this case its not working at all

Comment: That particular error is not a timeout error, though, so I doubt it has anything to do with the implicit wait.  If you're saying that you get the login screen loaded, and are able to send the user name and password AND click submit, and then the error happens, it would seem that there's additional code after the test that's failing?  Your error indicates that an image or icon webelement is not clickable

Comment: You right, its says element is not clickable, but that element is actually visible. Even if element is not visible, implicit wait supposed to wait, in my case its 45 sec.  Guess what, I put  thread.sleep(10000) after i pressed submit, so it waited untill page fully loaded and performed further steps. So Thread.sleep is saving this case for now. But i dont want to use sleep in the future.

Comment: I'll post my code for a fluent wait for clickable below.

Comment: It may be a case where the test is finding an element from the previous page that just happens to have the same locator, and that element may in fact not be clickable. It's hard to say though without seeing your other page object that is used after login, and, what your test is doing after it clicks submit to login.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my overloaded methods to wait for an element (or by) to be clickable.  The element version is hard-coded to wait 10 seconds, the other you pass the seconds to wait as a second parameter.  You get the idea.  Obviously, this would be used instead of the page object element.

```
/**
 * Wait until a web element is clickable by WebElement
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param ele - WebElement
 */
public void waitUntilClickable(WebElement ele) {

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));

}

/**
 * Wait until a web element is clickable by locator
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param by - By
 */
public void waitUntilClickable(By by, int seconds) {

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));

}
```

Comment: Great. I try this and let you know. Should I paste this code to my objects class? and what to do with implicit wait, keep it as same?                                                                  Thanks for your time Bill!

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static void WaitUntil(this IWebDriver driver, Func<bool> Condition, float timeout = 10f)
    {

        float timer = timeout;
        while (!Condition.Invoke() && timer > 0f) {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            timer -= 0.5f;

        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    }

driver.WaitUntil(() => driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[contains(@class, 'block-ui-wrapper')]").Length == 0);
```

I have a class of extensions where I do a bunch of custom Selenium operations. I find that the implicit waiting causes me more trouble than it is worth. And I find explicit selenium waiting can get a bit verbose, and it doesn't cover everything I need from it in my framework, so I've made a good number of extensions. Here is one of them. Note, I use the FindElements for the example above because I do not want an exception thrown if nothing is found. This should work for you.

Note: You will need to put this in a static class to be functional. Be careful when extending existing classes like this in logic, as it can confuse others when they are trying to determine where the methods are defined.

Here is my full extensions file, via a Github gist. I wrap almost all Selenium functions. I do a good bit of Javascript because JQuery is 100% reliable in finding elements, whereas Selenium's find function has some trouble inside things like IFrames. Additionally, JQuery has an extremely robust, and super-readable way of querying elements in the DOM using any number of locators, whether they be ID, Class, text contains, pseudo selectors etc; all in the same query string! (Lack of pseudo selector support in Selenium css selector can be a limitation) That is why I use it. It is much more readable than xpath, easier to write, and 100% reliable when written correctly. If you do not have JQuery on the tested pages, you can simply inject JQuery's script every time a new page is loaded.

So what I do is I use JQuery to find and generate an explicit XPath to the exact element I want on a page, and then I pass the exact XPath to Selenium's "Find" logic. When you hold Selenium's hand, there are no problems finding elements.

https://gist.github.com/tsibiski/04410e9646ee9ced9f3794266d6c5a82

**NOTE:** You can combine this with your above click logic to extend clicks and always wait until the object you are trying to click is ready for the click. With my extensions, you can wait for absolutely any condition you can think of, verses specific scenarios in explicit waits, and certainly the general waiting in implicit ones.

Note how, in my extension methods, I extend Element.Click() into Element.ReliableClick(). This not only handles harder-to-find elements, but it waits before clicking. Additionally, you can do a number of things in this abstracted extension function, such as custom reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix, you can add a call to `WebDriverWait.until()` in each of your page objects' constructors, like this: `webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(CSS_SELECTOR)))` where `CSS_SELECTOR` would be a locator that is *unique* to the page you need to wait for.

For example, if `CSS_SELECTOR` was an id, it would be `"#some-unique-id"`, if it were some unique class it would be `".some-unique-class"`, or a unique tag would simply be `"some-unique-tag"`

This will essentially wait for the page to load upon instantiating it with `LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver)`, or whatever page you need to instantiate.

In your `BaseClass` class you would need to add a `public static WebDriverWait webDriverWait` object and instantiate it like this: `webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, MAX_WAIT_SECONDS);` where `MAX_WAIT_SECONDS` is the maximum amount of wait seconds before it throws an exception.